# Using cfssl and multirootca for remote signing sends HTTP instead of HTTPS

Tags: ssl, openssl

After following Mike Newswanger's writeup on Building a Secure PKI for Kubernetes (https://www.mikenewswanger.com/posts/2018/kubernetes-pki/), I run last step in the guide to request the certificate from my client machine:

`cfssl gencert -config=request-profile.json -hostname=myhost.example.com -tls-remote-ca ca.pem -profile=default csr.json | cfssljson -bare myhost`

The error is

```
{"code":7300,"message":"read tcp 192.168.122.106:37618-\u003e192.168.122.1:8888: read: connection reset by peer"}
```

Using `tcpdump` on the multirootca host, I see that `cfssl` is sending an HTTP request when multirootca is expecting HTTPS.

Nothing in the cfssl documentation that I've been able to find indicates how to force cfssl to use HTTPS on cert requests, and Mike's post indicates that it should just "work" at this point.

Has anyone had success using the latest release of cfssl or am I missing something trivial?

**Note: I did have to modify the request-profile.json to remove the <:port> from the ca-server before I was able to get to this point**

Answer (score 2):

So after several trials/tribulations, the solution was pretty straightforward. In `request-profile.json` the URI needs to be `https://<ca_server>:<port>`.

This github issue https://github.com/cloudflare/cfssl/issues/898 helped point me in the right direction.

Also, if anyone else happens across this and are stuck, don't download the binaries from https://pkg.cfssl.org/ as they are severely outdated. Installing using Go is the best way to get the latest versions that actually work in the write-up mentioned in my Q (as well as the CloudFlare Blog).